# css parent child overwrite

Tags: css

I have a css problem. I got an table inside anther table. each table have a different color (depending data inside). So I put a class for each table. but the color depend when the class is set on css. I mean if color 1 is declare before the second, it will override the child color.

I made a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/b8T6V/2/ (complete version)

```
 <table border="0" class="Grid0">
        <tr class="even">
                    <td>table 1, row 1</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <table border="0" class="Grid1">
                    <tr class="even">
                        <td>table 2, row 1</td>       
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td>table 2, row 2</td>       
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>        
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>table 1, row 2</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
             <td>
                <table border="0" class="Grid1">
                    <tr class="even">
                        <td>table 2, row 1</td>       
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td>table 2, row 2</td>       
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>     
        </tr>
    </table> 


table.Grid0 tr.even
{
    background-color: RED ;
}
table.Grid0 tr.odd
{
    background-color: BLUE;
}

table.Grid1 tr.even
{
    background-color: BLACK;
}
table.Grid1 tr.odd
{
    background-color: WHITE;  /*background-color: blue;*/
}
```

If you use Grid1 instead of Grid0, and Grid0 instead of Grid1. That will not work.

jsfiddle sample:

The first table start with Grid0 and the second with Grid1. The second should have table in red/blue.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your inner `tr` is inside two tables, one of class `Grid0` and one of class `Grid1` then both sets of CSS rules apply, so (since they appear later on in the file) the back/white background colours take precedence.

The easiest way to fix this is to insert `> tbody >` in to all of the relevant rules, so that only the class of the parent table is considered and not any other ancestor tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more specificity to your second table's selector, as follows:

```
table.Grid0 tr.even, table table.Grid0 tr.even
{
    background-color: RED ;
}
table.Grid0 tr.odd, table table.Grid0 tr.odd
{
    background-color: BLUE;
}

table.Grid1 tr.even, table table.Grid1 tr.even
{
    background-color: BLACK;
}
table.Grid1 tr.odd, table table.Grid1 tr.odd
{
    background-color: WHITE;  /*background-color: blue;*/
}
```

Comment: I got too many possibilities. In the sample I got 2 possibilities, but I got at least 3 and its should evantualy be 8. is there another solution? (I just dont want to write every table and sub table)